# Invalid Grant (Error Code 70000) refreshing token Azure AD

Tags: azure, post, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure AD login to obtain an access token and be able to do a request to SharePoint Online using its API REST.

I am able to get this access token but, when I try to get the refresh token, I get an error.

In this moment I am testing this using Postman.

I am doing the following:

- I start calling the next URL to get the code:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&response_type=code
```

- When I receive the code, I do the following POST:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

```
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:{client_id}
client_secret:{client_secret}
code:{code_generated_previous_request}
redirect_uri:https://myapplication.com
resource:https://{mycompany}.sharepoint.com/
```

- I receive this response:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "AllSites.FullControl Directory.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All Sites.FullControl.All Sites.Read.All User.Invite.All User.Read.All User.ReadWrite.All",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "3599",
    "expires_on": "1559291698",
    "not_before": "1559287798",
    "resource": "https://{mycompany}.sharepoint.com/",
    "access_token": "XXXXXXXX...",
    "refresh_token": "YYYYYYYY...",
    "id_token": "ZZZZZZZZ..."
}
```

- Finally, I try to refresh token doing the following POST:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

```
grant_type:refresh_token
client_id:{client_id}
client_secret:{client_secret}
refresh_token:YYYYYYYY...
redirect_uri:https://myapplication.com
```

- But in this step, I get an error:

```
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70000: Provided grant is invalid or malformed.\r\nTrace ID: XXXX\r\nCorrelation ID: XXXXX\r\nTimestamp: 2019-05-31 09:35:39Z",
    "error_codes": [
        70000
    ],
    "timestamp": "2019-05-31 09:35:39Z",
    "trace_id": "XXXX",
    "correlation_id": "XXXX"
}
```

I have checked with URL Encode, without URL encode, removing the client_secret and redirect_uri parameters and other things, but I always get the same error. Surely, I'm making a stupid and obvious mistake, but I don't see which one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to renew your access token using `authorization code` and `refresh_token` grant_type.

I have partially reproduce the error you encountered. As shown below:

[image]

**Possible Reason Of Error:**

1. Though exact reason is unknown!
2. I am presuming your pasted refresh token wasn't valid. In this case
   you may encountered this error.
3. You have to paste the `refresh_token` which you have got on previous
   steps as it is. be sure you did exactly.

**Resolution Of Error:**

I am sharing the exact way to achieve your goal. Please have a look the below steps

**Step:1**

I am using `PostMan` for this case. Please fire up the PostMan and click on `Authorization` tab also select `Type` as `OAuth 2.0` finally click on `Get New Access Token`. See the below screen shot:

[image]

**Step:2**

When you would clicked `Get New Access Token` new window will be prompted just as given picture below. fill out this with your credentials.

***Request Format:***

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId/Name}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={applicationId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={yourURI}&response_mode=query&scope={yourScope}
```

[image]

When you click `Request Token` button you will be prompt login window. Login with your credentials.

**Step:3**

Open your `postman console` before login like below:

[image]

Once your login successful. You would get your code.

[image]

**Step:4**

After successful login Go to `postman console` `request body` segment. Just open it and copy your code. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Step:5**

Copy your `code` and and paste on `authorization_code` token request `code` textbox part. You would get your `access_token` `refresh_token` and `id_token`

***Request Format:***

> client_id:{ApplicationId}
>
> scope:{YourTokenScope}
>
> redirect_uri:{YourAppURI}
>
> grant_type:authorization_code
>
> client_secret:{YourApplicationSecret}
>
> code:{CodeOfPreviousStep}

Just like below way:

[image]

**Step:6**

This step copy your `refresh token` from previous stage (`step 5`) and paste on beside `refresh_token` textbox while requesting `grant_type:refresh_token` request. In response you would get your new `access_token` and `refresh_token`

***Request Format:***

> client_id:{ApplicationId}
>
> scope:{YourTokenScope}
>
> redirect_uri:{YourAppURI}
>
> grant_type:refresh_token
>
> client_secret:{YourApplicationSecret}
>
> refresh_token:{refresh_token Of Previous Step}

See the screen shot below:

[image]

### Note

1. Be sure you are coping exact `code` and `refresh token`
2. `Scope` optional for token renewal. You can renew your token without scope because your refresh token already contains your scope.

Comment: having issues in the steps, the same code which works on windows is not working in ubuntu.

Comment: This solution was provided based on windows not tested on ubuntu. If you have set azure credentials accordingly it should work everywhere.